Scope problem with Arc and RwLock in rust
encountered a problem as below, must I use &'static self or self instead of &self? Is there any other solution? Appreciate for any help
struct AuthToken {
    token: String,
    expires_at: i64,
}



pub(crate) struct Notifier {
    credential: Credential,
    auth_token: Arc<RwLock<AuthToken>>,
    http_client: reqwest::Client,
}


pub(crate) async fn push_notification<D>(&self, notification: PushNotificationBody<D>) -> Result<(), Error>
    where
        D: Serialize,
    {
        {
            // error occurs here 
            let mut auth_token = self
                .auth_token
                .write()
                .map_err(|e| Error::wrap(e, "获取读写锁失败(fcm notifier)", 500u16))?;
            let timestamp = chrono::Utc::now().timestamp();
            if auth_token.expires_at <= timestamp - 300 {
                let token = Self::generate_jwt_token(&self.credential, timestamp)?;
                auth_token.token = token;
                auth_token.expires_at = timestamp + 3600;
            }
        }
...
}



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors..

@kmdreko ok, I edited it

The error too, please. And can you elaborate what Error type you are returning is?

Although its difficult to judge based on information provided (the definition of Error would be helpful, Error::wrap() in particular), the problem is likely to be the error handling in case the RwLock fails to lock:
Remember that RwLock::write() returns a LockResult<RwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>>. In case locking fails, LockResult carries a PoisonError<RwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>>. This PoisonError has an into_inner()-method, which allows one to access to underlying data regardless of the fact that the lock is considered poisoned (if so wanted). This also requires the PoisonError to carry the same lifetime as the RwLockWriteGuard, as we need to be able to unlock the lock while the inner RwLockWriteGuard is being dropped. In other words, the error-indicating value of locking a Mutex or RwLock has locked the underlying, and carries a reference to that lock in order to unlock it. This is a common source of confusion in Rust.
In your particular situation, it seems like your Error-type might carry the error value e. This would require the reference to the lock to be of 'static lifetime, in order to return that error from the method. But the RwLockWriteGuard contained in PoisonError is borrowed from self.auth_token, so it only lives for as long as self. This is the error you are getting.
The solution is to drop the PoisonError (hence unlocking the lock, and dropping the borrow on &self) in the map_err()-call.

I refactored my code and elevated the Arc and Mutex up to their parent struct, it seems to work around the problem. But I agree with you, the LockResult may be the culprit,  I will try your solution later to make sure what incurred the problem, and thanks for your answer very much
